# Can't add files to Git

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and github and I am having trouble using Git. My path for Git looks something like this `C:\Program Files\Git\code_snippets`. And in the code_snippets directory I have a README.md file. Right now what I want to do is add another file like I see people in the tutorials I am watching are doing, but nothing seems to work.

I cannot create any files in the code_snippets directory only a folder, when I try using commands like `git add index.html` I get an error saying `index.html did not match any files`. the command `git status` says

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with origin
nothing to commit, working tree clean.
```

Nothing I seem to do adds a file to the code_snippets directory.

Comment: Have you created the file first? git doesn't create new files, just adds them in the list of already existing files to be commited.

Comment: You most likely get this error because the file is not present. So you should create the file first. Adding a file to a repository does not create it at the same time.

Comment: so if I had an index.html file in C:\xampp\htdocs\header how would I add this to the git repository. I am getting this error when I type 'git add index.html' fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: You cannot add a file which is not in a git repository. If you want to create a git repository inside C:\xampp\htdocs\header, you may do a `git init` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For adding files using `git add` , you need to have the files inside the local git repository (the local git repository will have a .git folder in it).

You cannot add some files which are outside of this folder to the repo. The files in a local repo are associated to the .git folder.

If the folder is an existing one and is not tracked by git, then do a `git init` inside the root folder whose content you want to track. This initialises a new git repo.

Answer (score 2):

`git add index.html` won't add a file to file system, it adds file to git only.

Use any editor to create index.html file in your code_snippets folder first, then use `git add index.html` to tell git to track this file